# Subtracting in SQL with update query creates long decimal

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm importing a text file containing a field with numbers up to the thousandth decimal as a number field. I'm then running and update query to fix the SSNs (preceding zeros) and subtract 500 from the number field.

```
UPDATE CODImportFile 
SET CODImportFile.[Original SSN] = Format([Original SSN],"000000000")
,   CODImportFile.[Lifetime Eligibility Used] = [Lifetime Eligibility Used]-500;
```

I have no clue why, but some of the results look like this:

```
Original:500.016
Result: 1.60000000000196E-02
```

Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: Firstly format SSNs `UPDATE CODImportFile SET CODImportFile.[Original SSN] = Format([Original SSN],"000000000");` then subtract `UPDATE CODImportFile SET CODImportFile.[Lifetime Eligibility Used] = [Lifetime Eligibility Used]-500;`

Comment: @Sami I get correct results when running this as a display query, but still has the same problem when running as an update query.

Comment: What is the data type of that `[Lifetime Eligibility Used]` field?

Comment: @HansUp I have it as a double

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the data type of `[Lifetime Eligibility Used]` is double, the calculation in your query is similar to this:

```
SELECT
    CDbl(500.016) - 500 AS difference,
    TypeName(CDbl(500.016)-500) AS data_type;
```

... which returns this:

```
difference           data_type
1.60000000000196E-02 Double
```

Those unexpected decimal places are an artifact of the imprecision inherent with decimal math on a binary system.  You could convert the field type to single (or cast double to single in the calculation), but then you would still get "extra" decimal places ... just a different set of values for those decimal places.

I think you should discard any decimal places you don't want to store.

```
UPDATE CODImportFile
SET [Lifetime Eligibility Used] =
    Round([Lifetime Eligibility Used]-500, 3);
```

Then you only need decide which rounding method you want.

```
? Round(0.1245, 3)
 0.124 

? CDbl(Format(0.1245, "0.000"))
 0.125
```

Comment: Answered my question perfectly. Bonus points for mentioning the rounding! I wasn't aware of the difference.

Comment: That "round to even" or "banker's rounding" aspect of `Round()` surprises many folks.  It's another reason why floating point arithmetic is hard.  Integer arithmetic is just so much easier.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably caused by SQL treating the number as a binary, when you are expecting Decimal results: some decimal fractions can not be represented as binary without rounding error.For example, .1 cannot be represented exactly.

See 
[Why can't decimal numbers be represented exactly in binary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089018/why-cant-decimal-numbers-be-represented-exactly-in-binary) for lots more info.

Answer (score 0):

The result there is the "correct" remainder after subtracting 500 from the original number (~0.016). Floating point numbers aren't exact anyway, which is why you have the `...00196` at the end. You should be able to fix this by specifying an appropriate scale (probably 3 in this case) in your decimal field in addition to precision.

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258832(v=sql.80).aspx:

> decimal[(p[, s])] and numeric[(p[, s])]
>
> Fixed precision and scale numbers. When maximum precision is used, valid values are from - 10^38 +1 through 10^38 - 1. The SQL-92 synonyms for decimal are dec and dec(p, s).
>
> p (precision)
>
> Specifies the maximum total number of decimal digits that can be stored, both to the left and to the right of the decimal point. The precision must be a value from 1 through the maximum precision. The maximum precision is 38. The default precision is 18.
>
> s (scale)
>
> Specifies the maximum number of decimal digits that can be stored to the right of the decimal point. Scale must be a value from 0 through p. Scale can be specified only if precision is specified. The default scale is 0; therefore, 0 <= s <= p. Maximum storage sizes vary, based on the precision.